# UV-Vis Absorption Spectra climbing at lower wavelengths

Tags: uv-vis-spectroscopy, absorption

I have run a sample of Pyrene in Ethanol and got a UV Vis absorbance spectra that starts climbing as it reaches the lower wavelengths. I am using quartz cuvettes and was wondering what could be the cause of this rise at the shorter wavelengths.

[image]

Here is the literature spectra.

[image]
Here is my measured spectra.

Comment: Please add more instrumental details. Is it a single beam instrument or a double beam instrument. What was your blank?

Comment: the solvent and quartz of your cell (depending on type of quartz) will start absorbing at shorter wavelengths.  You can minimise this to some extent using a matched blank cell.

Comment: @AChem it is a double beam instrument, however on this test run I did not use a blank

Comment: You should not use air as a blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you had given the reference for the literature spectra, I would be able to say for certain, but it's possible that they didn't use a quartz cuvette. According to [this website](https://qvarz.com/quartz-cuvettes-for-uv-vis-ir-spectroscopy/), quartz starts absorbing below ~200 nm. Looks like it depends on the type of quartz, and brand of cuvette, you've used (from [this link](https://airekacells.com/blog/cuvette-guide)):

[image: Different quartz types]

Comment: At wavelengths shorter than $200$ nm, everything absorbs the light, even glass, water or air. Absorption spectrum at these wavelengths must be determined in a vacuum.

Comment: @Maurice it didn’t occur to me how high that energy was (I’m used to working in wavenumbers)… but yeah, that makes sense